# handle Checkbox similar to tristate checkbox using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [data,setData] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      image1: name1img,
      image2: name1img_P,
      image3: name1img_S,
      name: "name1img"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image1: name2img,
      image2: name2img_P,
      image3: name2img_S,
      name: "name2img"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      image1: name3img,
      image2: name3img_P,
      image3: name3img_S,
      name: "name3img"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      image1: name4img,
      image2: name4img_P,
      image3: name4img_S,
      name: "name4img"
    }])
```

i am rendering the above data as a images using map function
i am saving every click of the image saving its id and name in 2 different arrays using e.target.id and e.target.alt. my problem is how to render name1img_P(primary) of the array first item and the remaining items as name1img_S(secondary) tried like this `<img src={selectedState[0] == item.id ? item.image2 : (selectedState.includes(item.id) ? item.image3 : item.image1)} alt={item.name} id={item.id} />`
[image: smaple image]
and

```
selectedState has ["1","2"]
```

and primary dark green and secondary has light green color background

Comment: Your code looks sufficiently good to do the job. What results are you getting ?

Comment: the secondary color was not reflecting on dom

Comment: If the images have transparency, then you should add `backgroundColor` style to the `<img>`'s parent element. Value of backgroundColor should be conditionally provided.

Comment: haa yes but i dont have transparent images that's why I'm struggling to do this

Comment: You can create svg filters to convert white to green or some other color using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/fecolormatrix . However, this will only work nicely if your image has only black & white color, otherwise it will become very complex. I would strongly suggest to convert white to transparent using any tool, or use svg icons for it.

Comment: Here's one such tool.
https://onlinepngtools.com/create-transparent-png

Answer (score 0):

You can do tristate checkboxes using React hooks like this (React 18).  This example does not use effects, but rather manipulates the DOM in the change handler which is more performant. Note that this approach is a general solution for using tristate in React without a library, and does not involve custom images, so it might not be what SO is looking for but may help others.

Say you have two checkbox inputs in your JSX, like this:

```
   <input 
      type="checkbox"
      name="name1"
      onChange={ event => handleChange(event) }
   />

   <input 
      type="checkbox"
      name="name2"
      onChange={ event => handleChange(event) }
   />
```

You need state for each checkbox's checked state - note the default state for each is “indeterminate" and the input name attributes are used for each key. The checked property holds three possible states, "indeterminate", "empty", or "checked".

```
   const [tristate, setTristate] = useState({
      name1: { checked: "indeterminate" },
      name2: { checked: "indeterminate" },
   })
```

The handleChange event handler for each checkbox is as follows. Note the two additional functions called in this handler, findState and setCheckState. Both are passed a single argument - the name attribute of the checkbox currently being changed.

```
   const handleChange = (event) => {
      const { name, type } = event.target
      if(type == "checkbox"){
         setTristate({ ...tristate,
            [name] : { checked: findState(name) }
         })
         return setCheckState(name)
      }
   }
```

findState() looks at the current tristate state and sets the next state, e.g., if current state is "checked", next state is "indeterminate".

```
   const findState = (name) => {
      if(tristate[name].checked=='checked'){
         return 'indeterminate'
      }
      if(tristate[name].checked=='empty'){
         return 'checked'
      }
      if(tristate[name].checked=='indeterminate'){
         return 'empty'
      }
    }
```

setCheckState() manipulates the DOM to set the checked or indeterminate properties of the checkboxes.

```
   const setCheckState = (name) => {
      const el = document.getElementsByName(name)[0]
         if(el){
            if(tristate[name].checked == "empty"){
                return el.checked = true;
            }
            if(tristate[name].checked == "checked"){
                return el.indeterminate = true;
            }
            return el.checked = false;
        }
    }
```